# Store date in mysql from select option in a form

Tags: php, html

I have a form that has `<select>` and `<option>` for selecting the date of birth by selecting the day, month and year.

The way I am think of inserting it using STR_TO_DATE() but the problem I'm having is creating a string from the `<select>` and `<option>` part of the form. The form is like below but with more options of course. I will be using php to pass to the database but to create the string I don't mind method use to create the string.

```
<select name="Day">
   <option selected> Day</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: What PHP code are you using to this. Show us some code

Comment: SO what is the question or problem you are having?

Comment: How do you expect us to help when you don't give an obvious question?..

Comment: [php's strtottime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) concat your `option` pass as str `$d = strtotime(str)` make sure your string is disambiguous do some further processing if required for mysql then save/update or whatever

Comment: I thought it was obvious I'm trying to take the value from 3 `<select>`and `<option>` e.g. 3 1 2012 which will be then converted to 2012-1-3 to be added to a datebase. So how do you create a string from 3 drop down boxes. I didnt include the php code because it is not nessecary.

Answer (score 4):

mysql stores dates in yyyy-mm-dd format.

you could easily just concatenate your dropdown fields into that format to store in the database:

```
$date = $_POST['Year']."-".$_POST['Month']."-".$_POST['Day'];
echo $date;
```